# Google Fonts don't work in Firefox

Tags: css, .htaccess, firefox, fonts

I really can't use the Google Fonts in Firefox. Basically i have one font from Google Fonts, it works fine in other browsers, but, in the firefox, the font doesn't work.

My Source:

HEAD:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And, i have tried to put that .htaccess file, but it doesn't work:

.htaccess:

```
# BEGIN REQUIRED FOR WEBFONTS

AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# END REQUIRED FOR WEBFONTS
```

Anybody saves me?

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is for sites, that _host_ the fonts. That is, Google sends such a header. All you need to do is use the font in your CSS. Please open Firefox's console with `Ctrl-Shift-K`. Are there any messages?

Comment: Oh dude, i have fond the answer, it's basicaly delete the "sans-serif" from font-family.

Comment: Glad it works now. Keep the above `.htaccess` snippet in mind, when once you host your font files on your own server, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Font not rendering correctly in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031864/google-font-not-rendering-correctly-in-firefox)

Answer (score 6):

I figured out a major fix for getting Google Fonts to work in Firefox.

This fix involves adding an @font-face to your stylesheet.

Oddly enough it was by accident, while I was in firefox.

In Firefox, go to Google.com/fonts and find your font in the list.

Assuming it has rendered correctly, highlight a portion of the text, right click and Inspect Element.

If your inspect element is side mounted, on the bottom labels, and if it is bottom mounted, on the right side labels, select "Fonts" next to rules/computed.

You should now be able to see CSS code related to your chosen font. It uses DIFFERENT links than what Google gives to you in their stylesheets.

For your PT Sans, this should work.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "PT Sans";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local("PT Sans"), local("PTSans-Regular"),     url("http://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=fQl5KuJ0t7CxaofpRWHFZ5uy9QftGgiCbPT5J2Tle6QGEtCW0q5T6QHEAICoCh1h9R715REvNVFz5maQ3RAjMvuvYlUZxjWJuWoIFYd8ZVs9VGRJmXaKNSd0UG6XHo4E") format("woff2"), url("http://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=9HC7E4PH-EC-60ASiiwijJuy9QftGgiCbPT5J2Tle6QGEtCW0q5T6QHEAICoCh1h9R715REvNVFz5maQ3RAjMvuvYlUZxjWJuWoIFYd8ZVs9VGRJmXaKNSd0UG6XHo4E") format("woff");
}
```

Also, when you use apply the font family, do it this way

```
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif !important;
```

That has worked for every font for me so far.

I know I'm a bit late but if you still don't have a fix I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i had this problem too. I was missing "," element. I had `font-family:'Open Sans' sans-serif;`Than i added `,` after `'Open Sans'`, and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just had same problem, and debugger was nice!
Removing cursive from the line 
    font-family:'Tangerine' cursive, 'Arial, Helvetica';

to this

```
font-family:'Tangerine', 'Arial, Helvetica';
```

solved it for firefox :)